# Suggested Edit Reviewers shooting down one tag edits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I just reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4910087) suggested edit. I thought it was valid, and although I was tempted to deem it "too minor", I ended up approving it.

I like to only mark edits as "too minor" if the user who suggested the edit could *easily* have found other things in the post to improve. Is this a good practice? In this case, I didn't see anything else the user could have improved, so I approved the edit.

Three of the reviewers who reviewed this edit marked it as "too minor", and got the edit rejected.

Afterwords, when I discovered that this edit had been rejected, I went to the post and made the edit anyways.

Did I make the right decision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A one-tag edit may be essential.  For example, no programming language tagged, or worse, the wrong language.  In such cases, I would accept the suggestion.

Removing a tag like [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) is a very minor edit.  Removing the tag is completely in order.  Putting it in the review queue is not.

I would have rejected that edit suggestion as well, for being too minor.