# Is it better to make meaningful one-tag edits or leave questions mis-tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

Although rather new to SO, one of the things I’ve done to try and contribute is to keep a tag that I follow ([webforms]) “clean” by removing the tag when a question **clearly** doesn’t involve the Microsoft ASP.Net Web Forms programming model (e.g., Drupal questions often end up tagged with it).  When I make those changes, I’ll also clean up the post to the extent I can (e.g., correcting spelling and grammar, maybe clarifying the title).  But often, since the question usually involves technologies I don’t use, I’m hesitant to make too many content changes for fear of changing the OP’s meaning.   Most of the time, my edits are approved, but on occasion that are not (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5176298) which leaves the content objectively mis-tagged.

Occasionally, I’ll also run across a post that I think could really use a tag (such as [Does Fortran modify input arguments through subroutine multiple calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465490/), where the crux of the issue was a FORTRAN question and it wasn’t tagged with [FORTRAN]).  However, it got me thinking when someone posted that my edit was “too minor”.  Of course, it’s perhaps likely that the reason anyone saw the question so it could be answered was because I had added this key tag.

The above could be considered rep farming, although at a couple of +2s a day my newborn will be in college before I’d make it to moderator this way.  I think what I’m doing is contributing in the way that I can to overall SO hygiene, but maybe not so much. So, my question is: **is what I’m doing constructive?** This seems to suggest that it can be ([Suggested Edit Reviewers shooting down one tag edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256278/suggested-edit-reviewers-shooting-down-one-tag-edits)) . If it’s not, I’ll go back to mostly lurking – but I can’t see exactly how SO would be better off with more mis-tagged content floating around rather than less.

Comment: Actual moderators are elected rather than appointed by rep BTW. Though it is true that greater moderation tools do become available with rep these users are known as 10k users or (for 20k with delete privileges) "trusted users" not moderators.

Comment: @MartinSmith I think you can see from my lack of knowledge about such things just how focused I am about gaining rep "by any means necessary"...8-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The rule when you are suggesting edits is to **fix everything that is wrong with the post**, not *just* the tags. When you are doing that—or at least fixing *most* everything, then there is no problem.

Indeed, as you point out, cleaning up tags is an important contribution to the overall quality of the site. The problem is simply that when low-reputation users suggest edits, they have to be approved by a minimum of 3 other experienced users. Which we don't mind doing if you're actually improving the site. If you're not, you're wasting time that we could be spending doing that on our own. This is why "too minor" is one of the canned rejection reasons. As with everything, exercise discretion.

More specifically, [the edit you call out as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5176298) looks reasonable to me. I probably would not have rejected it as "too minor". There are no obvious problems that you failed to fix. Personally, I would have done something with the title. But it isn't terrible as it stands now, and writing a good title is hard, so you can be forgiven for that.

Also, while we're on the subject: version-specific tags (like [asp.net-mvc-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc-4)) are discouraged unless a question is *specific* to that version. I'm no subject expert, but it looks to me like that question should have just been tagged with [asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc). At worst, it should carry both tags, the general one and the version-specific one.

[The Fortran question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465490/does-fortran-modify-input-arguments-through-subroutine-multiple-calls) is an even better example of appropriate tag editing. There, the poor use of tags is strongly decreasing the question's likelihood of getting an answer. That's a clear case, at least to me, where adding an essential tag is ***not*** too minor. The only time I'd reject an edit like that as "too minor" is if it failed to fix other obvious problems like unformatted code. And I wouldn't actually reject it, I'd "improve" it, making the appropriate edits myself.

Comment: Your comment on the title is a perfect example of my thought around "if you don't know the technology, you first should do no harm to the OP's question" philosophy. I'm not an MVC programmer, so I wasn't sure I could clarify the subject much without the risk of munging it up.

Comment: "If you don't know the technology, you first should do no harm to the OP's question" - is this, then, the "Hopper-cratic" oath?

Answer (score 3):

As someone who saw, and answered, the [Fortran question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24465490/) only because of that single tag edit, it's hard for me to say that adding the tag was too minor an edit.

That said, three points:

- The question paragraph was terribly formatted;
- The question was almost an identical duplicate of a (now deleted) question: the asker seemingly unaware of the edit function;
- The code formatting in the question was hideous: largely the reason I hadn't attempted to examine the duplicate.

The second wouldn't have been reasonable for you, or the reviewers, to know.  The third is wise to avoid fixing unless one is very sure that the indentation isn't the problem (it wasn't, but it is, after all, fixed-form source code): reasonable for you to ignore.  I can't speak for the commenter on the question, but it's possible he would have been aware of both these points.

Perhaps, then, a little effort on the formatting of the question may have been good.  Perversely, the original alternative version was much better formatted there.

In conclusion, I'd say it was a valid edit.  If, on the other hand, the question already had the [fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) tag I'd say that adding the [fortran77](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran77) (for example) - because it's looks Fortran 77-like - would be too minor.

Comment: Your comment on the code formatting is a perfect example of my thought around "if you don't know the technology, you first should do no harm to the OP's question" philosophy. I've not written a line of FORTRAN in nearly 25 years (and very few even then!), so I wasn't sure I knew enough to fix formatting without the risk of munging up how FORTRAN is supposed to look these days.  Although, I suspect, FORTRAN hasn't changed much since my college days.

Comment: Fortran certainly isn't mean to look like that these days, but the chances are good that if someone is posting code in what looks like fixed-form source they don't realize that that is important.  Unless the code is clearly free-form source it's always best to leave formatting alone until the asker has a chance to comment.